# SharePoint 2010 and WF 4.0

Tags: workflow

Does anyone know if there are any plans to upgrade SharePoint 2010 to use WF 4.0, for example in a service pack?

Or do we have to wait for the next version of SP? in 2013?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft haven't indicated that a service pack will provide .Net 4.0, and it's clear that a good amount of re-engineering/regression testing would be required for this to happen.

In the absence of any official information, I'd design around the platform you have now.

HTH,

Chris.